# Como faço para usar as funções do OpenSSL no VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, openssl

Existe uma DLL que eu possa usar as funções do OpenSSL, para trabalhar com assinaturas, PEM, etc.? Como trabalhar com ela?

Answer (score 2):

Dê uma olhada no projeto [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/). Nunca utilizei, nem sei qual a completude da API, etc, mas é o único que conheço que entrega uma solução mais ou menos pronta.

Outra opção seria escrever você mesmo os `PInvokes` e as estruturas.

Comment: Obrigado, Vinicius! 
Então, eu tentei o montar as estruturas das dll que o próprio openssl fornece, mas não consegui.
Eu encontrei uma dll com o nome de ManagedOpenSSL, consegui importar no sistema e estou verificando as funções, mas não  muita coisa a respeito dela lib.
Mas obrigado por ora!

Comment: `PInvoke` é bem chato de fazer mesmo... depois que acerta funciona perfeito, mas até lá é complicado. Não conhecia essa lib. Boa sorte!

Comment: Isso é verdade, e sem falar que eu precisava descobrir as funções escritas nessas dll, que até então também não encontrei.
Obrigado!

Comment: Não seja por isso: `https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html` e `https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html`

Comment: Opá, agora posso ver se consigo me divertir um pouco, hehe
Obrigado mesmo, Vinicius! 
Grande Abraço!